# Changing labels in matplotlib polar plot

Tags: matplotlib, python-2.6

I am using matplotlib to create polar plots to represent Rose Diagrams. Right now the plot is getting created perfectly. I want to replace the angles being displayed on the axis with direction names: N for 0 degrees, W for 90 degrees, S for 180 degrees and E for 270 degrees.

The current rose diagram looks like the following:
[image]

Note: I have tried with windrose but this output is more appropriate for my purpose. Hence a good way of assigning custom labels to the axes will be very helpful.

The python version I am using is 2.6 with matplotlib version 1.2.0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that you have an axes object `ax` you can do simply do something like this

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['N', '', 'W', '', 'S', '', 'E', ''])
```

or get some inspiration by [this old example](http://youarealegend.blogspot.de/2008/09/windrose.html)

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code as follows:                rose=fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
rose.set_xticklabels(['N', '', 'W', '', 'S', '', 'E', ''])   and it worked

Comment: That's exactly what I ment: my `ax` is what you call `rose`

Comment: You might want to consider shifting  "zero degree" to the top.
 ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2)